# cmake find_package relative path in CMakeLists.txt subfolder

Tags: c++, cmake, find, package

I have the following file structure and would like to use a cmake config file `MYLIBConfig.cmake` which is used by all `CMakeLists.txt` files in the projects to include headers located in a folder `include` on the top level.

```
MYLIBConfig.cmake
include/
    header_a.h
    header_b.h
src/
    project_a/
        CMakeLists.txt
        main.cpp
    project_b/
        CMakeLists.txt
        main.cpp
```

A `CMakeLists.txt` containts the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

find_package(MYLIB REQUIRED PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../)

project(projecta)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(projecta main.cpp)

message(${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # Outpus /include/ which is the problem. Should be a relative path to the include folder

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
            ${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        )
```

The MYLIBConfig.cmake has currently the following content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

#message(${PREFIX})

set(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/include/)
```

With this setup, I am not able to include the headers in my main.cpp files using `#include "header_a.h"` because they are not found.

The problem is that I don't know if my usage of `find_package` is correct because the set variable `MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS` is just `/include/` when I use `message(message(${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})` inside the `CMakeLists.txt`. Is there a cmake variable that I can use in the `MYLIBConfig.cmake` file that sets a path which is relative to the "currently active" `CMakeLists.txt`? Or is there another way to achieve a working include using a config file? I know that I could just use a relative path inside the `target_include_directories` of every `CMakeLists.txt` but I would like to use a config file to have the flexibility of changing the include folders and possibly set more variables. In the config file I also tried to use ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} and ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} but these variables did not work either.

**EDIT**

Another way I think it could work is when the `MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS` would result in a global path. Would this be the appropriate way? And how could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the global path in `MYLIBConfig.cmake` with [CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html):

```
set(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/)
```

Or if you want a relative path to the [currently processed source](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) you can get it accordingly with [file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#path-conversion):

```
file(RELATIVE_PATH MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/)
```